# Iterate combinations of characters in multiple lists where the output string is in a specific order

Tags: python, string, list, iteration, concatenation

I'm trying to create a Python script with itertools where:

I have 4 lists, each containing single characters:

```
li1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
li2 = ["d", "e", "f"]
li3 = ["q", "w", "e"]
li4 = ["t", "y"]
```

and I would like to output all possible permutations of the following, in this specific order:

```
li1 + li2 + li3 + li1 + li4 + li1
```

where `li` is a string/character in the list, and the sequence/order cannot be changed

Being a novice all I can think of is iterating through each list as a loop but I don't know how to do it 4 times concurrently

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your "lists" are sets..

Comment: Have you read the [documentation for itertools](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#module-itertools)? It should help.

Comment: You refer to `li1` as both a list (actually set) and an item in a list. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `itertools.product()` for this:

```
import itertools

li1 = ["a","b","c"]
li2 = ["d","e","f"]
li3 = ["q","w","e"]
li4 = ["t", "y"]

for elem in itertools.product(li1, li2, li3, li1, li4, li1):
  print elem
```

(I've taken the liberty of changing your sets into lists. The code, however, will also work with sets, except that order of permutations will be different.)

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm :)